# Finding the speed

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Charles and Smith left a place abc at the same time and stated moving in the same direction.Charles speed was $15$ Kmph and Smith's speed was $12$ kmph.Half an hour later Anthony left the place and and travelled in the same direction.Sometime later he overtakes Smith and $90$ minutes further on he overtakes Charles.What is Anthony's speed?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is it a typo between "Kpmh" and "mph" ? Do you mean kilometer or mile ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! This site requires that you show the effort you have made. Knowing where you are stuck also helps us frame more suitable answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of the people is the following. (Assuming Charles and Smith leave at $t=0$, and we use $km$ and $hour$ unit)
$$
C(t) = 15t \\
S(t) = 12t \\
A(t) = v(t-0.5)
$$
At some point they meet :
$$
A(t) = S(t) \implies v(t-0.5) = 12t \\
A(t+1.5) = C(t+1.5) \implies v(t+1) = 15(t+1.5)
$$
Solving these equations give $t = 1.5,\ v = 18$.

Comment: The first equation seems right but the second equation is flawed.You did not give an account for the distance travelled by Charles in that sometime when Anthony overcomes Smith.

Comment: You are right ! Also $v=13$ is actually impossible since Anthony cannot overtake Charles...
I edited !